# C++ node.js Addons - Explanation of parameters in Init()

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

Can someone explain the difference between the one-argument form and the two-argument form of Init when creating a c++ node.js addon?

```
void Init(Local<Object> exports) {}
void Init(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object> module) {}
```

Comment: @Rich Remember, use 4 spaces to format code would be more readable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you could always use the second method template, but `exports` or `module` provide different options.

Using the following example:

```
void Init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "test", MyTest);
}
```

will add the function `test` as a "function property" on your exports object.

So you could use the following JS code and it would, for example, print it out to the stdout using the `test` function from your exports object:

```
const test = require('./path/to/node/addon/addon.node');
test.test('my message');
```

On the other hand:

```
void Init(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object> module) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(module, "exports", MyDummyCallback);
}
```

Provides you with the full module (`module`) and allows you to override your exports. You could call something like this from JS:

```
const test = require('./path/to/node/addon/addon.node');
test('test');
```

Will print your `test` message to the tty using the overridden module.